# aerospike cluster crashed after index creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aerospike, nosql

We have a cluster at AWS of 4 machines t2micro (1cpu 1gb ram 15gb ssd) and we were testing aerospike.
We used the aws marketplace AMI to install aerospike v3 community edition, and configured only the aerospike.conf file to have a namespace on the disk.

We had one namespace with two sets, totaling 18M documents, 2gb ram occupied and aprox 40gb of disk space occupied.
After the creation of an index in a 12M records set the system crashed.

Some info:

aql on the instance:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ aql
2015-09-16 18:44:37 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLIENT Socket write error: 111
Error -1: Failed to seed cluster*
```

Tail of the log: (it keeps adding only lines repeated)

```
Sep 16 2015 19:08:26 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2406) device /opt/aerospike/data/bar.dat: used 6980578688, contig-free 5382M (5382 wblocks), swb-free 0, n-w 0, w-q 0 w-tot 23 (0.0/s), defrag-q 0 defrag-tot 128 (0.0/s)
Sep 16 2015 19:08:46 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2406) device /opt/aerospike/data/bar.dat: used 6980578688, contig-free 5382M (5382 wblocks), swb-free 0, n-w 0, w-q 0 w-tot 23 (0.0/s), defrag-q 0 defrag-tot 128 (0.0/s)
Sep 16 2015 19:09:06 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2406) device /opt/aerospike/data/bar.dat: used 6980578688, contig-free 5382M (5382 wblocks), swb-free 0, n-w 0, w-q 0 w-tot 23 (0.0/s), defrag-q 0 defrag-tot 128 (0.0/s)
Sep 16 2015 19:09:26 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2406) device /opt/aerospike/data/bar.dat: used 6980578688, contig-free 5382M (5382 wblocks), swb-free 0, n-w 0, w-q 0 w-tot 23 (0.0/s), defrag-q 0 defrag-tot 128 (0.0/s)
```

asmonitor:

```
$ asmonitor -h 54.XX.XXX.XX
request to 54.XX.XXX.XX : 3000 returned error
skipping 54.XX.XXX.XX:3000
***failed to connect to any hosts
```

asadm:

```
$ asadm -h 54.XXX.XXX.XX -p 3000
Aerospike Interactive Shell, version 0.0.10-6-gdd6fb61
Found 1 nodes
Offline: 54.207.67.238:3000
```

We tried restarting the instances, one of them is back but working as a standalone node, the rest are in the described state.
The instances are working, but the aerospike service is not.

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide dedicated to using [Aerospike on Amazon EC2](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/deploy_guides/aws/) and you probably want to follow it closely to get started.

When you see a AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLIENT "Failed to seed cluster" it means that your client cannot connect to any seed node in the cluster. A seed node is the first node the client connects to, from which it learns about the cluster partition table and the other nodes. You are using `aql` with the default host (`127.0.0.1`) and port (`3000`) values. Try with `-h` and `-p`, or use `--help` for information on the flags.

There are many details you're not including, such as are these nodes all in the same Availability Zone of the same EC2 region? Did you configure your `/etc/aerospike.conf` with mesh configuration (that's the mode needed in Amazone EC2). Simply, can your nodes see each other? You're using what looks like public IP, but your nodes need to see each other through their local IP addresses. They have no idea what their public IP is, unless you configured it.  At the same time the clients may be connecting from other AZs, so you will need to set up the [`access_address`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/general/#what-is-access-address-) correctly. See this [discussion forum](https://discuss.aerospike.com) post on the topic: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/problems-configuring-clustering-on-aws-ec2-with-3-db-instances/1676

Comment: Sorry, it was so many things that I didn't know what else to provide to enrich the question. We tried putting hosts after the aql command but we got the same error response.

All the nodes were on the same AZ, and the conf file was set to use mesh with two of the four clusters IPs in all instances. We configured the nodes to  use the internal IPs to connect.

Today out of nowhere the nodes come back to live and all were working normally. We still don't know what happened.

Comment: If aql cannot get to it, neither can any other client. We've seen cases where nodes from other AZs _sometimes_ can connect to the private IPs and sometimes can't. The easiest way to tell if your app (client) nodes can connect is to telnet to each server node's IP and port. Glad it's working, you can always follow up on the discussion forum.